# how to debug app on specific device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I have app minSdk 21 and on sony phones app is not working how it supose to. How can I debug it without owning sony phone? Android studio doesn't have emulators other than Nexus and Pixel. I tried Genymotion but they have only sdk 19 sony emulators. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Did you resolve this question?

Comment: No, still looking for solutions

Comment: There is paid options online as well.  Why don't you lower your min sdk?

Comment: Too many changes needed if I will lower min sdk

Comment: The sony phone you tested on, what sdk does it have?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/about-us/app-player.html#gref) before?

Comment: Bluestacks its just android emulator which doesnt even have option to select between devices